# Determine the controller, action, and ID of the given URLs

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

Determine the controller, action, and ID of the given URLs. Recreate and complete the table on a clean sheet of a paper.[This is the table that need to answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD1FO.png) Please help for my assignment thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, MVC-based implementations route urls as - controller/action/id - so in your example too, you can deduce using the same pattern from the endpoints mentioned in your first column in the image. (for ex: if it says `test/pre/1000`, then it will be `TestController`, Action method is `pre` and id is `1000`). For action the default value is `Index`, if you do not find anything after the controller name in the endpoint.

I suggest to do a bit more research on it online. I'm sure it will not be tough to find an answer for your question or any follow up such questions, pretty quickly. Please refer this as a first - https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc - explains clearly and it almost answers your question directly. Look at the `URL Pattern` and `Configuring a Route` sections in that link. Once you follow that in your hands-On trials and you still face issues in routing that is when stackoverflow can be an appropriate forum to find answers for your real time hurdles. Hope this helps.